# MySQL GROUP By Only when Two column matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group a record only if two of the fields repeat themselves.
I am designing a social sharing photo app. users can share, like and comment on thers photo. Each action (share, comment, like) will appear on their friends wall.

The Problem is that when a user do all the three actions, the picture appears three times instead of one with the three action on it.

Data in database is like this (activities_tb)

```
id | photoID | uiID  | action  | date
-------------------------------------------
 1 |  1      |  2    | like    | 01/01/2015
 2 |  1      |  2    | share   | 02/01/2015
 3 |  1      |  4    | share   | 03/01/2015
 4 |  1      |  2    | comment | 04/01/2015
 5 |  2      |  4    | like    | 04/01/2015
 6 |  2      |  2    | like    | 05/01/2015
 7 |  2      |  3    | share   | 05/01/2015
 8 |  2      |  4    | comment | 06/01/2015
 8 |  3      |  3    | like    | 07/01/2015
 9 |  3      |  5    | like    | 08/01/2015
10 |  3      |  5    | comment | 08/01/2015
```

The query result I want to get

```
id | photoID | uiID  | action  | date
-------------------------------------------
 3 |  1      |  4    | share   | 03/01/2015
 4 |  1      |  2    | comment | 04/01/2015
 6 |  2      |  2    | like    | 05/01/2015
 7 |  2      |  3    | share   | 05/01/2015
 8 |  2      |  4    | comment | 06/01/2015
 8 |  3      |  3    | like    | 07/01/2015
10 |  3      |  5    | comment | 08/01/2015
```

This is my statement

```
SELECT id, photoID, uiID, action, date
FROM activities_tb
GROUP BY photoID, uiID.
```

This combines all the photos by their id returning only three results

I will be glad if anyone can be of help, thank you

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02bfa9/1 I get more than 3 results u_u

Answer (score 0):

You can first select required ids and join on your table:

```
select tb.* 
from activities_tb tb
join(select max(id) as id 
     from activities_tb
     group by photoID, uiID) t on t.id = tb.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "SELECT DISTINCT"

```
SELECT DISTINCT photoID, uiID, action, date
FROM activities_tb
GROUP BY photoID, uiID.
```